# primitive array to map using a stream api java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to create a map from primitive array of integers where key is index and value is element by current index. How can i do it using a Java Stream API?

I'm trying to do something like this but it doesn't work out for me.

```
        IntStream.range(0, nums.length)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> nums[i]));
```

Comment: It’s must faster to look at Javadoc instead of waiting for help from strangers.

Comment: Could you explain ["but it doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntStream` doesn't have the `collect()` method you are trying to use, so you have to convert your `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map =
    IntStream.range(0, nums.length)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> nums[i]));
```

Comment: the same answer is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57638246/8359623 why do you give a repeated answer when you could ping the link as well.

Comment: @PapaifromBEKOAIL - I disagree with you. OP's problem is not about how to do it; rather, it's about why his code is not working.